# If we can calculate RTT using timestamps in TCP options then why do we use the value of the backed off timer to compute next RTT in karn's algo?

Tags: tcp

I am new to learning networking concepts. This might be stupid question but please resolve this doubt. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I do not know Karn's algorithm, but I presume it is part of (at least one) one of TCP's flow control/congestion avoidance algorithms out there.

But this much can be said: TCP timestamps are *optional*.

In the absence of TCP timestamping, there still needs to be a way to observe and adjust the flow behaviour of a given TCP session. This essentially means keeping track of the intervals and time deltas (= RTT) of incoming ACKs for segments sent out previously, and adapting sending rates accordingly.